# Evaluating an improper integral using the method of residues

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{ dx }{1+x^6}$. $\mathbf{Attempt:}$ Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^6} $. The singularities are given by $z^6 = -1 = e^{i \pi + 2 i\pi k}$. And so, by simple calculation, the roots of $f$ are $z_k = e^{\pi i(1 + 2k)/6} $ where $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$.  We know the points $z_0,z_1 $ and $z_2$ lie above the real axis and so we can choose $R$ large enough so that they lie inside the curve $\Gamma_R= \gamma_R + \mu_R$ where $\gamma_R$ is the semicircle of radius $R$ and $\mu_R$ is the line $[-R,R]$. Therefore,

$$ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) = \lim_{R \to \infty} \left( \int_{\gamma_R} f(z)dz + \int_{-R}^R f(x) dx \right) $$

We know since $|z+w| > |z|-|w|$ that $|f(z)| = \frac{1}{|1+z^6|} \leq \frac{1}{|z|^6 - 1} \leq \frac{1}{R^6 - 1} $ and so

$$ \left| \int_{\gamma_R} f(z)dz \right| \leq \frac{ lenght( \gamma_R ) }{R^6-1} = \frac{ \pi R}{R^6 - 1} \to 0   $$

Therefore,

$$ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(x)dx = \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{k=0}^2Res (f,  z_k) $$

and so

$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^6} = 2 \pi i \sum_{k=0}^2Res (f,  z_k) $$

Here is where I got stuck. First of all, how can I make the integral go from $0$ to $\infty$ and not from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ? Also, is there an easier way to calculate the residues of these function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand is even, so the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is just half the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

To compute the residues, since the poles are simple zeros of the denominator, we have
$$
\operatorname{Res} (f,  z_k) =\frac{1}{6\,z_k^5}.
$$
I do not thing that there is an easier way.